# C++17 pointer_traits implementation

Tags: c++, reinventing-the-wheel, c++17, template-meta-programming

`pointer_traits` is a lightweight trait that provides a uniform interface to builtin pointers and user-defined fancy pointers. That said, things like `element_type` require
template metaprogramming techniques to determine. This makes `pointer_traits` a good exercise.

Here's my re-implementation under the name `my_std::pointer_traits`, put in a separate header `pointer_traits.hpp` because `<memory>` is way too comprehensive:

```
// C++17 pointer_traits implementation

#ifndef INC_POINTER_TRAITS_HPP_60HzB0lbek
#define INC_POINTER_TRAITS_HPP_60HzB0lbek

#include <cstddef>     // for std::ptrdiff_t
#include <memory>      // for std::addressof
#include <type_traits> // for std::add_lvalue_reference

namespace my_std {

  template <class Ptr>
  struct pointer_traits;

  namespace pt_detail {

    template <class Tmpl>
    struct get_first_param { };
    template <template <class, class...> class Tmpl, class T, class... Args>
    struct get_first_param<Tmpl<T, Args...>> {
      using type = T;
    };
    template <class Tmpl>
    using get_first_param_t = typename get_first_param<Tmpl>::type;

    template <class Tmpl, class U>
    struct rebind_first_param { };
    template <template <class, class...> class Tmpl, class T, class... Args, class U>
    struct rebind_first_param<Tmpl<T, Args...>, U> {
      using type = Tmpl<U, Args...>;
    };
    template <class Tmpl, class U>
    using rebind_first_param_t = typename rebind_first_param<Tmpl, U>::type;

    template <class Ptr>
    auto element(int) -> typename Ptr::element_type;
    template <class Ptr>
    auto element(long) -> get_first_param_t<Ptr>;

    template <class Ptr>
    auto diff(int) -> typename Ptr::difference_type;
    template <class Ptr>
    auto diff(long) -> std::ptrdiff_t;

    template <class Ptr, class U>
    auto rebind(int) -> typename Ptr::template rebind<U>;
    template <class Ptr, class U>
    auto rebind(long) -> rebind_first_param_t<Ptr, U>;

  }

  template <class Ptr>
  struct pointer_traits {
    using pointer = Ptr;
    using element_type = decltype(pt_detail::element<Ptr>(0));
    using difference_type = decltype(pt_detail::diff<Ptr>(0));

    template <class U>
    using rebind = decltype(pt_detail::rebind<Ptr, U>(0));

    static pointer pointer_to(std::add_lvalue_reference<element_type> r)
    {
      return Ptr::pointer_to(r);
    }
  };

  template <class T>
  struct pointer_traits<T*> {
    using pointer = T*;
    using element_type = T;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;

    template <class U>
    using rebind = U*;

    static pointer pointer_to(std::add_lvalue_reference<element_type> r)
    {
      return std::addressof(r);
    }
  };

}

#endif
```

I used [N4659](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/) as a reference.

Comment: Do you have a test program?  Or at least a motivating example of where this is useful?

Comment: I'd like to know what the `rebind` member is for - that's one thing that's not also in `iterator_traits<T*>`.

Comment: @TobySpeight, from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/pointer_traits : `template <class U> using rebind  ---> Ptr::rebind<U> if exists, otherwise Template<U, Args...> if Ptr is a template specialization Template<T, Args...>`. In simple words, it converts a given pointer of T to the same class of pointer to U. This is a very common operation for pointers (e.g. when allocating nodes, you need to transform the pointer to the element type to the pointer of the node type). It is not so common to need this with iterators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried a little bit your code and seems to work.

If you want my opinion (review?) I find the techniques quite arcane.
Perhaps it is my C++17 perspective, or maybe that the code you posted needs to be compatible with C++98 or 11 (?).
I will base my review on the C++17 perspective since that is one of the labels of your post.

First, I would factor out the manipulation of the first argument in a single class:

```
template<class> struct first_param {};

template<template<class, class...> class Tmpl, class T, class... Args>
struct first_param<Tmpl<T, Args...>> {
    using type = T;
    template<class U> using rebind = Tmpl<U, Args...>;
};
```

Second, I would replace the trick of `int`, `long`, matching plus `decltype` with a modern tool designed to detect valid operations on types, which is [`std::experimental::detect_or_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected).

The class basically will tell if an operation is valid on a type and if not a fallback type is used.

These are the operations that hypothetically need to be applied to the type,

```
template<class T> using element_type_t = typename T::element_type;
template<class T> using difference_type_t = typename T::difference_type;
```

The tricky one is the one that rebinds:

```
template<class U>
struct bind_second {
    template<class T> using rebind_t = typename T::rebind<U>;
};
```

Note that at the end it is simply adding a level of indirection.

As powerful as `detect_or_t` is, I profoundly dislike its syntax because it is impossible to figure out the meaning from reading: the first argument is the fallback, the second argument is the operator and the third argument is the target (probed) type.

For this reason, I rearrange the `dectect_or_t<fallback, operation, target>` into a metafunction that is more readable `valid_on<operation, target>::otherwise<fallback>`:

```
    template<template<class...> class Op, class Target>
    struct valid_on {
        template<class Fallback> using otherwise = std::experimental::detected_or_t<Fallback, Op, Target>;
    };
```

This way each fallback case is read as in the documentation, that is in plain English:

```
template <class Ptr>
struct pointer_traits {
    using pointer = Ptr;

    using element_type    = typename valid_on<element_type_t   , pointer>::otherwise<typename first_param<Ptr>::type>;
    using difference_type = typename valid_on<difference_type_t, pointer>::otherwise<std::ptrdiff_t                 >;
    template<class U>
    using rebind          = typename valid_on<bind_second<U>::template rebind_t, pointer>::otherwise<typename first_param<Ptr>::rebind<U>>;

    static constexpr pointer pointer_to(std::add_lvalue_reference<element_type> r) {
        return Ptr::pointer_to(r);
    }
};
```

Finally, I encapsulate the needed functionality in a base class and add the `T*` specialization.
The final full code looks like this:

```
template<class> struct first_param {};

template<template<class, class...> class Tmpl, class T, class... Args>
struct first_param<Tmpl<T, Args...>> {
    using type = T;
    template<class U> using rebind = Tmpl<U, Args...>;
};

class pointer_trait_detail {
 protected:
    template<class T> using element_type_t = typename T::element_type;
    template<class T> using difference_type_t = typename T::difference_type;
    template<class U>
    struct bind_second {
        template<class T> using rebind_t = typename T::rebind<U>;
    };
    template<template<class...> class Op, class Target>
    struct valid_on {
        template<class Fallback> using otherwise = std::experimental::detected_or_t<Fallback, Op, Target>;
    };
};

template <class Ptr>
struct pointer_traits : private pointer_trait_detail {
    using pointer = Ptr;

    using element_type    = typename valid_on<element_type_t   , pointer>::otherwise<typename first_param<Ptr>::type>;
    using difference_type = typename valid_on<difference_type_t, pointer>::otherwise<std::ptrdiff_t                 >;
    template<class U>
    using rebind          = typename valid_on<bind_second<U>::template rebind_t, pointer>::otherwise<typename first_param<Ptr>::rebind<U>>;

    static constexpr pointer pointer_to(std::add_lvalue_reference<element_type> r) {
        return Ptr::pointer_to(r);
    }
};

template <class T>
struct pointer_traits<T*> {
    using pointer = T*;
    using element_type = T;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;

    template <class U>
    using rebind = U*;

    static pointer pointer_to(std::add_lvalue_reference<element_type> r) {
        return std::addressof(r);
    }
};
```

Here is the full working code (in a namespace `stx`), alongside your code (in namespace `my_std`) and some test cases: https://godbolt.org/z/zGMhEssoc

It works with GCC and clang (C++17 mode).
Unfortunately `clang` requires inserting a few `::template`  keywords spinkled that make the code a bit less readable (as seen in the Godbolt link).

If you find an error in my code I appreciate corrections.

Comment: Thanks for the review!  I agree that the detection idiom would make the code more straightforward than using the "arcane techniques" of overload resolution, and I like the syntax `valid_on<Op, T>::otherwise<Fallback>` that you proposed.  I guess `std::conditional_t<requires { typename T::member_type; }>, typename T::member_type, Fallback>` would also be an option now that we have concepts (still, it would be a good idea to wrap it and eliminate the repetition of `typename T::member_type`).

Comment: The part about the `template` keyword is new to me — I was actually under the impression that this is ill-formed, but it seems not :/  I will come back to cast my accept after a while.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, the `std::conditional_t<requires ..., typename T::member_type, ...>` would not work because it will give a hard error on the second argument when it doesn't exists.

Comment: I can't give an explanation for `template` and also find gcc and clang to be inconsistent about its need. (the godbolt link has all the `template` necessary for clang). I tend to intuit them lately when things do not work.

Comment: I found [Equivalent of "typename", to indicate that a dependant name is indeed a 'template template parameter'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33417989) on Stack Overflow, where two (unfortunately unsourced) answers both suggest that this usage of `template` here is valid.  Also, good point about my `std::conditional_t` proposal generating a hard error.

Comment: `::template` is used in your posted code.

Comment: I was under the impression that this usage of `template` must be followed by a template argument list (i.e., `X::template Y<Z>`), and I was not aware that it is valid even without the `<Z>` part.